# Problems with a responsive navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to build a responsive navigation bar. I'm using a `<nav>` element that contains an `<img>` and a `<ul>`element. I have set up media queries so that when the screen is resized, some of the `<li>` elements are hidden with the `display: none` property. The problem occurs when I click on the menu icon. It's supposed to display the hidden menu items but it doesn't. 
Could someone please have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dkaw0yx/) and tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I'm still learning the ropes. Could you please give me instructions if I do something incorrectly instead of downvoting me immediately? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
    if (x.className === "nav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "nav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("home/pexels-photo-4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;    
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {   
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);    
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav {  
    float: right;
    padding-top: 50px;  
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav li { 
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;   
}

.nav li a {
    color: #fff;   
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    font-size: 16px;  
    font-weight: 600;   
}

ul.nav li a:hover,
ul.nav li a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;  
    color:#fff;
}

ul.nav a:hover:before, 
ul.nav li a:focus:before {
    width:100%;
    background:#fff; 
}

ul.nav a:before {
    content:'';
    height:2px;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    right:auto;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition: .4s; 
}

.nav li.icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:765px) {

    .nav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}  

@media screen and (max-width:765px) {
    ul.nav .responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.nav .responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;   
    }
    ul.nav .responsive li {   
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    ul.nav .responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav {
        padding-top: 20px; 
    }
    .nav li a {
        font-size: 14px; 
    }

    .logo {
        margin: 0;
        width: 110px;
        height: 70px;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="images/logos/marcon logo white on trans copy 2.png">        
  <ul class="nav" id="myNav">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-label="Home"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: I've enclosed the link for the fiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo Links to any off site resource are not encouraged since they could disappear.  Use a snippet and put the code in the question itself.  Apart from this, not seeing jQuery in your fiddle.  Bootstrap requires it.

Comment: `myFunction` could be implemented as `myFunction() { $('#myNav').toggleClass('responsive') }`

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo You got downvotes because this stuff *is* explained.  You're asking people to put extra effort in to understand your question when apparently you put no effort in working out how to ask a good question.  Take the [tour].  Read [ask] and provide an [mcve].

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't understand why my question isn't good. I explained what the issue is, what the code is supposed to do and asked you guys to tell me why that wasn't so.

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo probably because someone saw a "why isn't my code working" question with no actual code or error logs (and yes, I'm aware that there are no error logs in this case) and knee-jerk down voted the question simply because it doesn't *look* good.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Good to know, will bear that in mind.Some folks seem to forget they were once new at this as well :)  Thanks for the links.

Comment: You see the 1st comment is that you don't show code and 2 people agreed (comment has 2 up votes).  jsFiddle is great, but fiddles get deleted - which ruins a question, so put at least some code in the question itself.  If you get downvotes in the first few minutes for a very active tag like javascript it can kill your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in CSS. You wrote

```
ul.nav .responsive li
```

but since your function gives the "responsive" class to the `ul` element with the "nav" class you need to get rid of the space to declare that it is the `ul` element with both the "nav" and "responsive" classes:

```
ul.nav.responsive li
```

Comment: Thank you, that made the `li` items show. Now I need to figure out how to make the `nav` wrap around them.

Comment: Additional information: Try your code on codepen.io and get rid of the body, link and script tags. For some reason jsfiddle keep saying that myFunction() was not declared. This was fixed by changing the editor to codepen.

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo then please mark this as an correct answer. Thank you

Comment: @Crankeedoodledoo it already does wrap around them. Right now you only need to style the menu for a mobile device (in column instead of a row)

Answer (score -1):

For starters you have an extra closing body tag within your HTML. I would add a event listener to target the click of your logo, then add the function toggleBody which allows you to open and close your nav when you click the logo. Your question was vague but what i did understand is that you wanted this event to happen when you clicked the logo.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('logo').addEvenetListener('click', toggleBoy)
      function toggleBody() { 
        var showElements = this.querySelectorAll('.nav')[0];
             if(showElements.style.display === 'none') {
                 showElements.style.display = 'block';
             }else{
                 showElements.style.display = 'none';
             }
```

Comment: Tried to comment but seeing how I have under 50 points I cannot @tib

Comment: The OP already had his function connected to the menu, albeit using an "onclick" HTML attribute and the function was working correctly.